# How to link in std C++ library on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: c++, hyperlink, clang, osx-mavericks, libstdc++

I'm porting an application to OS X Darwin and am getting link errors with missing symbols like:

```
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
                       std::__1::allocator<char> >::find_last_of(char const*,
                                                                 unsigned long,
                                                                 unsigned long) const
operator delete[](void*)
typeinfo for std::runtime_error
std::set_unexpected(void (*)())
std::exception::~exception()
[...]
```

I expect these should come from libstdc++ but I don't see how to link that in using clang.

Here is my attempted link line and the resulting failure:

```
clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -m64 -o ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/myExec ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/myExec.o ../../src/netcomm/ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/libmyExec.a ../../src/common/ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/libcommon.a -L../zlib  -lz -L../Botan -lbotan-1.10 -lboost_thread-mt
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
[...]
```

But this did not work, I'm not finding any examples of how to link it in correctly.

Comment: I think you have to invoke the C++ compiler and linker by using the `clang++` command instead.  The `clang` executable is the C compiler.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Linux trying to build one project with clang and libc++. That project had a binary linked with a third-party dynamic lib built with g++ and linked with libstdc++ (installed via package manager). Once I got rid of that dependency, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `-lc++` to the link line like this:

> clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ -m64 -o ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/myExec ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/myExec.o ../../src/netcomm/ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/libmyExec.a ../../src/common/ARCH.darwin_1310_i86/release/libcommon.a -L../zlib  -lz -L../Botan -lbotan-1.10 -lboost_thread-mt

After adding that, the missing symbols go away.

Comment: @Rico Is that better now?  This does solve my problem and was not provided in the other answer, the key was adding `-lc++`, the adding of `-std=c++11` `-stdlib=libc++` were already in my link line, so the other answer did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CLang++ compiler on my MacBook Pro OS X Mavericks 9.2, within NetBeans 7.4, I have

```
-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall
```

I am sure that I obtained the libc++ from installing the latest Xcode Command Line Tools for Mavericks.  On my system, the dynamic libc++ libraries are located in the `/usr/lib` directory.

**Start Edit**
I have just tried a basic, "Hello, World," run from Xcode, making sure the LLVM 5.0 (CLang++) compiler settings within the .xcodeproj are configured for:

```
C++ Language Dialect        C++11 [-std=c++11]
C++ Standard Library        libc++ (LLVM C++ Standard library with C++11 support)

C Language Dialect          c11
```

All works as expected.
**End Edit**

Comment: Using `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` on the link line gives the same missing symbols.  See edited question.