# Linking to a C++ library that has extern "C" functions

Tags: rust, ffi

So I'm writing a Rust FFI to a C++ library that has an extern "C" block with C-style function headers within it.   And my low-level FFI builds.

However, when I use my FFI in another project, it doesn't link properly, and I get undefined reference to operator new(), delete(), etc.

My question is:

1. Am I screwed because this is C++ and you can't link Rust to C++ yet?
2. Should the application consuming the FFI library deal with the linking issue somehow, and if so, how?
3. Can my libsomething.a be built somehow to include these C++ components, and if so, how?  I'm currently using the gcc crate rather generically.
4. put your own solution here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dynamically link to `libstdc++` to get the symbols your C++ code will need. You can instruct `rustc` to do so in your build script:

```
extern crate gcc;
use std::default::Default;

fn main() {
    gcc::compile_library("libhello.a", &Default::default(), &["cpp/hello.cpp"]);
    println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=stdc++");
}
```

[See full example on github](https://github.com/renato-zannon/rust-to-cpp-example)

For more info on build scripts, see [the Cargo guide](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html).

Comment: This worked for me as option 3 above.  I've since got it working w/o the gcc crate, but needed to add `-L native=$outdir -l static=$libname` to the rustc-flags in the println!()

Comment: The linked example repo is broken, as `Cargo.toml` specifies `*` for the `gcc` crate version without providing `Cargo.lock`. Back when the example was created, that would have resulted in using `v0.1.5` of the crate, but the code will now try to use the last release `v0.3.55`. Additionally, `gcc` has been deprecated and replaced by the `cc` crate.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on macOS using the [cmake](https://docs.rs/cmake/0.1.35/cmake/) crate.

```rust
// build.rs
extern crate cmake;

fn main() {
    let dst = cmake::Config::new("my_c_lib")
        .no_build_target(true)
        .always_configure(true)
        .build();

    // This was the fix
    println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=c++");

    // The cmake crate outputs the static lib in the build subdir in the cargo $OUT_DIR,
    // which is a little different than their docs show.
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}/build", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=my_c_lib");
}
```

Note that I have the C/C++ code as a git submodule under `native/`, and that project is using cmake.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22650261/172106) also helped.

Comment: `println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=c++");` works on Mac!